# Unable to add active class to current selected menu using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wanted to make current selected menu highlighted using jquery 
Following is my jquery code

```js
$('ul li a').click(function() {
  $('li').removeClass();
  $(this).parent().addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: #d90000;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Meetings</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="/home/index" onclick="onBegin()">Meeting Overview</a>
      <a href="/usermeetings/index" onclick="onBegin()">Meeting Details</a>
    </div>
</ul>
```

Please help

Comment: I placed the code in a snippet for you and replace the ASP code with the actual output HTML so that it can be executed here. Note that you're missing a `</li>` tag. With that said though, your code appears to work fine. Assuming the page is actually being transferred, then you simply need to set the class on load, based on the current loaded page.

Comment: It looks like it works, what's the problem?

Comment: Close the </li> tag and then try..

Comment: Try closing your li tag just before you close your ul

Comment: You're not actually removing any classes with `$('li').removeClass();`, you should be using `$('li').removeClass('active');` if you want to “toggle” the class.

Comment: This can´t work as expected. The problem is, you click the link (<a>) the current li elemet gets the class "active" and then you refresh the page because the link redirects you, which removes the active class from the current li element.

Comment: Actually in code </li> code is there i missed to copy here but it is not working in my side. I have put my jquery in  $(document).ready(function () { in Layout of MVC project.

Comment: Now what happening is when my pages reloads that class removed automatically.

Comment: @Schlangguru exactly that's my problem, so what's the solution plese tell me?

Comment: @C.jacking View my awnser: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42691740/1638059

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to make sub menu use this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if (localStorage.getItem('current_page')) {
        var page = localStorage.getItem('current_page');
        $('ul li').removeClass('active');
        $('ul li[data-page="'+page+'"]').addClass('active');
    }
});

$('ul li > a').click(function() {
   $('li').removeClass('active');
   $(this).parent().addClass('active');
   var page = $(this).parent().attr('data-page');
   localStorage.setItem('current_page', page);
});
```

Comment: Now what happening is when my pages reloads that class removed automatically.

Comment: also add data-page="meeting" on <li> element

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('ul li a').click(function() {
  //$('li').removeClass();
  //$(this).parent().addClass('active');
     $(this).parent().addClass('active');
     $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass("active");
});
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: #d90000;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Meetings</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <li> <a href="javascript:void(1)" onclick="onBegin()">Meeting Overview </a> </li>
      <li> <a href="javascript:void(2)" onclick="onBegin()">Meeting Details </a> </li>
    </div>
</ul>
```

Comment: Now what happening is when my pages reloads that class removed automatically.

Comment: problem still the same when page reloads it removes the class

Answer (score 0):

In your code, $(this).parent() is your <li> element only when you click your first link, links under dropdown-content div have not an <li> parent, so, the removeClass() function is not working as you expected.
Please, changethis and tell us if your code works as you expect.

Comment: Now what happening is when my pages reloads that class removed automatically.

Comment: Yes, javascript is client-side. If you need preserve it, you have to tell your page what is the current element when page reloads... But, if you are reloading your page, you can highlight your selected option by server-code...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
$('ul li a').click(function() {
  $(this).parent().addClass('active');
  $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass("active");
});
```

```css
ul li{
    list-style-type:none;
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0 10px;
    padding:5px;
}
ul li.active{
  background:pink;
}
li a{
  text-decoration:none;
  outline:0;
}
ul li.active a{
  color:#000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
        <li class="dropdown">
             <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Menu1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
             <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Menu2</a>
        </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can´t work as expected. The problem is, you click the link () the current li elemet gets the class "active" and then the page refreshes because the link redirects you, which removes the `active` class from the current li element.

What you can do is teh following:

**Option 1:** Get the current path from the url

When the page gets loaded, you can extract the path and add the `active` class to the li that contains the link:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var currentPath = window.location.pathname;
    $('a[href="'+currentPath+'"]').partent().addClass("active");
});
```

This will find the link with the currentPath and add the class `active` to the corresponding `li` element.

You also need to wrap all links in separate list-elements:

```
<ul>
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Meetings</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/home/index" onclick="onBegin()">Meeting Overview</a></li>
                <li><a href="/usermeetings/index" onclick="onBegin()">Meeting Details</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

---

**Option 2:** Add the active link name as Query Param

You can append a query param to your links like this:

```
<li class="link home">
    <a href="/home/index?page=home" onclick="...">Meeting Overview </a>
</li>
<li class="link usermeetings">
    <a href="/usermeetings/index?page=usermeetings" onclick="...">Meeting Details </a>
</li>
```

In your javascript you can then get the page param and add the `active` class like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var page = $.url().param('page');
    $('.link').find('.' + page).addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: using this $(document).ready(function() {
    var currentPath = window.location.pathname;
    $('a[href="'+currentPath+'"]').partent().addClass("active");
}); it shows all anchor tags items selected not the parent li. I am very near to solution by your code, please help a little more

Comment: `console.log(currentPath)` and see if it matches with your links.

Comment: but it is highlighting anchor tag of li but i need li to be highlighted.

Comment: See the updated awnser. I added the proper formatted html you need to use.

Comment: I am using Option 1 but it highlight the submenu, i want the main menu of that submenu to be highlighted. for eg. Meetings of 'Meeting Overview '

Comment: I need some code of yours to get this. Can you provide a jsFiddle?

Comment: You just have to use the right Selector https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/